# Javascript: Do properties of `document` include nodes beyond `body`?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm reading through [Mozilla's Introduction to DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_Reference/Introduction), and found one of their examples interesting - where `body` appeared as a property of `document`. This was atypical to me because I had only seen examples of nodes being accessed using `get`.

I tried three different ways of accessing the `body` element of `document`,

```
document.body.appendChild(_someNode_)
document['body'].appendChild(_someNode_)
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(_someNode_)
```

and found the example shown in Mozilla to be a nice shorthand (*first line*).

At this point, I felt that I could simply *chain* nodes with this shorthand, but found that it was undefined for anything but `body`.

Here's an example:

```
console.log(document.body); // #document
console.log(document.body.p); // undefined
console.log(document.body.getElementsByTagName('p')[0]); // <p></p>
```

What's going on here?

Comment: _“What's going on here?”_ – nothing’s going on here, `document.body` references the `body` element of an HTML document for convenience, and that’s it.

Comment: body, head, and documentElement all refer to specific and default HTML elements present in valid html. they are shortcuts to these common tags, but anything more specific and you'll need to use DOM methods or children[n] paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some tags that get their own properties in `document`, but they are rare, and in some cases are browser-dependent. An example would be `document.forms` that contains the collection of all form tags, and `document.frames`, that contains a collection of al frames and iframes contained by a page.

But you should avoid these properties, and use instead `.getElementById()`, `.getElementsByTagName()`, and the more recent and versatile `.querySelector()` and `.querySelectorAll()`

Comment: You discourage using `document.body`, which is available in [all browsers](http://quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_htmlOld.html "The table for document.body has a Yes in all of the columns, including IE5"), yet in the same breath suggest using `querySelector()`, which is [not supported by all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector#Browser_Compatibility "Only available in IE since version 8").

Answer (score 0):

The Document object is special. It has a property called [body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.body) that returns the `<body>` element, but in general you have to use `getElementsByTagName()` and its friends.